# Question about sharing mmapped area between 2 different processes

Tags: c, pointers, process, shared-memory, mmap

I'm trying to share mmapped area in 2 processes.
In my program, I create memory_update() process and memory_read() process.
This memory_update() process update mmapped area and tried to read that area in memory_read() process.
But I got when I tried to read the mmapped area.
So far, I don't have good luck to find a solution for this problem.

If you have any idea, please leave your comments.
Here is the source code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define COLUMN 80
#define ROW 10
#define BUFSIZE 80

#define SHM_KEY 0x9998

struct _row {
   int32_t flag;
   unsigned char *buffer;
};

typedef enum {
   DATA_READY,
   DATA_RESET
} msg_type_t;

struct _ipc_message {
   msg_type_t type;
   int32_t value;
};
typedef struct _ipc_message ipc_message_t;

typedef struct _row row_t;

int32_t format_number_string(char *buf, int32_t num)
{
   sprintf(buf, "%02d", num);
   return 0;
}

int32_t update_row(char *buf, char *str)
{
   strncpy(buf, str, 80);

   return 0;
}

int32_t print_row(char *buf)
{
   printf("print_row buf = %p\n", (void *)buf);
   printf("%s\n", buf);
   return 0;
}

int32_t memory_update(int32_t sk)
{
   row_t *p_row;
   ipc_message_t msg;
   unsigned char *shared_mem;
   unsigned char *ptr;
   char rbuf[BUFSIZE];
   char nbuf[3];
   int32_t shmid;
   int32_t i;
   int32_t ret;
   int32_t fd;

   shmid = shmget(SHM_KEY, ROW * sizeof(row_t), 0644 | IPC_CREAT);
   if (shmid == -1)
   {
      perror("Shared Memory Error");
      return -1;
   }

   /* Attach Shared Memory */
   shared_mem = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
   if (shared_mem == (void *)-1)
   {
      perror("Shared Memory Attach Error");
      return -1;
   }

   fd = open("testfile", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
   if (fd < 0)
   {
      perror("File Open Error");
   }

   ptr = mmap(
            NULL,
            COLUMN * ROW,
            PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
            MAP_SHARED,
            fd,
            0);

   printf("ptr = %p\n", (void *)ptr);
   for (i = 0 ; i < ROW ; i++)
   {
      format_number_string(nbuf, i);
      memset(rbuf, 0x20, BUFSIZE);
      sprintf(rbuf, "LINE %s :", nbuf);
      rbuf[strlen(rbuf)] = ' ';
      rbuf[BUFSIZE-1] = 0x0;
      update_row(&ptr[i * COLUMN], rbuf);
   }

   for (i = 0 ; i < ROW ; i++)
   {
      p_row = (row_t *)&shared_mem[i * sizeof(row_t)];
      p_row->flag = 0x99;
      p_row->buffer = &ptr[i * COLUMN];
//    print_row(p_row->buffer);
   }

   msg.type = DATA_READY;
   msg.value = 0;
   send(sk, (void *)&msg, sizeof(ipc_message_t), 0);

   i = 0;
   for ( ; i < ROW ; i++)
   {
      p_row = (row_t *)&shared_mem[i * sizeof(row_t)];
      if (p_row->flag == 0x0)
      {
         printf("row[%d] has processed\n", i);
      }
      else
      {
         i--;
         sleep(1);
      }
   }

   /* Detach Shared Memory */
   ret = shmdt(shared_mem);
   if (ret == -1)
   {
      perror("Shared Memory Detach Error");
      return -1;
   }

   ret = munmap(ptr, COLUMN * ROW);
   if (ret != 0)
   {
      printf("UnMapping Failed\n");
      return -1;
   }
   close(fd);

   return 0;
}

int32_t memory_read(int32_t sk)
{
   row_t *p_row;
   ipc_message_t msg;
   unsigned char *shared_mem;
   int32_t shmid;
   int32_t ret;
   int32_t i;

   while (1)
   {
      ret = recv(sk, (void *)&msg, sizeof(ipc_message_t), 0);
      if (ret < 0)
      {
         perror("recv error");
         return -1;
      }
      if (msg.type != DATA_READY)
      {
         continue;
      }
      else
      {
         break;
      }
   }

   shmid = shmget(SHM_KEY, ROW * sizeof(row_t), 0644 | IPC_CREAT);
   if (shmid == -1)
   {
      perror("Shared Memory Error");
      return -1;
   }

   /* Attach Shared Memory */
   shared_mem = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
   if (shared_mem == (void *)-1)
   {
      perror("Shared Memory Attach Error");
      return -1;
   }

   for (i = 0 ; i < ROW ; i++)
   {
      p_row = (row_t *)&shared_mem[i * sizeof(row_t)];
      printf("memory_read process [%d]\n", i);
      print_row(p_row->buffer);
      p_row->flag = 0x0;
      sleep(1);
   }

   /* Detach Shared Memory */
   ret = shmdt(shared_mem);
   if (ret == -1)
   {
      perror("Shared Memory Detach Error");
      return -1;
   }

   return 0;
}

int32_t main(void)
{
   pid_t pid;
   int32_t sp[2];
   int32_t ret;

   static const int32_t ps = 0;
   static const int32_t cs = 1;

   ret = socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, sp);
   if (ret == -1)
   {
      perror("socketpair");
      return -1;
   }

   pid = fork();
   if (pid == 0)
   {
      close(sp[ps]);
      memory_update(sp[cs]);
   }
   else
   {
      close(sp[cs]);
      memory_read(sp[ps]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

And this is the output.

```
$ ./mmm
ptr = 0x7fdc214a8000
memory_read process [0]
print_row buf = 0x7fdc214a8000
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Modifed code to mmap before forking.
And it is working as expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define COLUMNS 80
#define ROWS 60
#define BUFSIZE 80

typedef enum {
   DATA_PRODUCED,
   DATA_CONSUMED
} msg_type_t;

struct _ipc_message {
   msg_type_t type;
   int32_t value;
};
typedef struct _ipc_message ipc_message_t;

int32_t memory_update(int32_t sk, char *buf)
{
   ipc_message_t msg;
   int32_t ret;
   char *msg2 = "updated buffer";

   printf("memory_update : 1.buf = %s\n", buf);
   memset(buf, 0, 80);
   strncpy(buf, msg2, strlen(msg2));
   buf[strlen(msg2)] = 0;

   printf("memory_update : 2.buf = %s\n", buf);
   printf("memory_update : send message from memory_update process\n");
   msg.type = DATA_PRODUCED;
   msg.value = 0;
   send(sk, (void *)&msg, sizeof(ipc_message_t), 0);

   while (1)
   {
      printf("memory_update : receive message from memory_read process\n");
      ret = recv(sk, (void *)&msg, sizeof(ipc_message_t), 0);
      if (ret < 0)
      {
         perror("recv error");
         return -1;
      }
      if (msg.type != DATA_CONSUMED)
      {
         continue;
      }
      else
      {
         break;
      }
   }

   printf("memory_update : 3.buf = %s\n", buf);
   return 0;
}

int32_t memory_read(int32_t sk, char *buf)
{
   ipc_message_t msg;
   int32_t ret;
   int32_t i;
   char *msg3 = "buffer processed";

   printf("memory_read : 1.buf = %s\n", buf);

   while (1)
   {
      printf("memory_read : receive message from memory_update process\n");
      ret = recv(sk, (void *)&msg, sizeof(ipc_message_t), 0);
      if (ret < 0)
      {
         perror("recv error");
         return -1;
      }
      if (msg.type != DATA_PRODUCED)
      {
         continue;
      }
      else
      {
         break;
      }
   }
   printf("memory_read : 2.buf = %s\n", buf);

   memset(buf, 0, 80);
   strncpy(buf, msg3, strlen(msg3));
   buf[strlen(msg3)] = 0;

   printf("memory_read : 3.buf = %s\n", buf);
   printf("memory_read : send message from memory_update process\n");
   msg.type = DATA_CONSUMED;
   msg.value = 0;
   send(sk, (void *)&msg, sizeof(ipc_message_t), 0);

   return 0;
}

int32_t main(void)
{
   pid_t pid;
   int32_t sp[2];
   int32_t ret;
   int32_t fd;
   int32_t i;
   char *ptr;
   char *msg1 = "initial message";

   static const int32_t ps = 0;
   static const int32_t cs = 1;

   fd = open("80bytes", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
   if (fd < 0)
   {
      perror("File Open Error");
   }

   ptr = mmap(
            NULL,
            80,
            PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
            MAP_SHARED,
            fd,
            0);

   memset(ptr, 0, 80);
   strncpy(ptr, msg1, strlen(msg1));
   ptr[strlen(msg1)] = 0;
   printf("ptr = %s\n", ptr);

   ret = socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, sp);
   if (ret == -1)
   {
      perror("socketpair");
      return -1;
   }

   pid = fork();
   if (pid == 0)  /* child process */
   {
      close(sp[ps]);
      memory_update(sp[cs], ptr);
   }
   else  /* parent process */
   {
      close(sp[cs]);
      memory_read(sp[ps], ptr);

      ret = munmap(ptr, 80);
      if (ret != 0)
      {
         printf("UnMapping Failed\n");
         return -1;
      }
      close(fd);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `p_row->buffer = &ptr[i * COLUMN];` <<-- You are putting pointers in SHM. These pointers point into the mmap()ped area, but mean nothing to the receiver (the receiver does not have this area mapped) Instead of pointers, you should just put the actual char[] buffer payload  into SHM.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to do is sharing the mmapped area between 2 process without buffer copy (if possible). And tried to use shared memory to do that. But it seems that does not work. Is there any way to share mmapped area between 2 processes?

Comment: Mmap() it **before** fork()ing.

Comment: I'm going to rewrite the code with the idea of mmapping before forking.

Comment: Putting pointers into shared memory is still a bad idea.

Comment: I made a change to do mmap before forking. And it is working as expected!